# How to get Geo points of a location in google map of a website

Tags: .net, google-maps, google-chrome, web, web-crawler

I am trying to find out Geo( Lat/Long) points of a location.I am using http://courses.swingbyswing.com/courses/United-States/MD/Laurel/Patuxent-Greens/13986 website. There is google map. google map has a **red** color map point. I am trying to find out **lat/long** of this map point. but i am not able to do this task.

please any one help me.

Comment: Check the page source. The map is a div with background property set. The background url contains your lat/long.

Comment: @janek2012- i am trying to get location of **Bird's Eye Map** . please click on any buttom from 1 to 18. and see a **red** color map point

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. If you would like to get the Bird's Eye Map locations, check the script just before body closing tag. There is a `App.bootstrapData` variable with all the informations you want (JSON).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the maps -> Inspect element. 
or
Right click anywhere on the page -> View source

You will see the following:

```
<div class="map-image" style="background: url(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x120&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:red%7Clabel:S%7C39.0878863434392,-76.8416793644428&amp;sensor=false&amp;visual_refresh=true&amp;zoom=15) no-repeat center center"></div>
```

the lat/long is shown here

```
label:S%7C39.0878863434392,-76.8416793644428
```

maybe the lat: 39.0878863434392 and long: -76.8416793644428